# two lists side by side

Tags: html, css

I can't get two lists to sit side by side. 
the second list always sites just below the first list. 
they need different divs because they will be colored and populated differently. 
The list will also be really long and populated through JS so I can't simply build the lists with position relative

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LmxT2/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="left_list">
   <div id="item_name">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="item">
   <ul>
    <li>some name</li>
    <li>some name</li>
    <li>some name</li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#item_name {
 color: #0000FF;
 font-size: 17px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 208px;
 text-align:right;
}    

#item_name li{
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#item {
 margin-left: 208px;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 17px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 background-color: red;
}

#item li{
list-style-type: none;
}

#left_list {
 background-color: #CDCDCD;
 width: 208px;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
margin-right: 22px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LmxT2/3/)**

**CSS**

```
#left_list {
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    float: left; /* add this new style in css*/
    width: 208px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float:left` will do the trick. However, I did some other arrangements to your code. Site architecture is very important to eliminate spaghetti code. And lastly, try not to use ID as much. Use classes instead. ID's you can only  use once in a page, whereas classes you can use as much as you need to ;)

Here is the [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/LmxT2/5/)